# Not show the login view when the user is already connected SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, firebase-authentication

I'm creating an app with authentification in Swift and SwiftUI. I use Firebase Authentification. The ViewRouter change the view when the user sign in or sign up, but when the app restart, the LoginView show up. I think it's because the ViewRouter is setting to go to the LoginView by default. I would like to switch it to the HomeView if the user is already signed in.

Thank you for your help.

The ViewRouter :

```
class ViewRouter: ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentPage: Page = .signPage
}

enum Page {
    case signPage
    case homePage
}
```

The view which change the destination :

```
struct MainView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter
    var body: some View {
        switch viewRouter.currentPage {
        case .signPage: SignView(isLogin: .constant(false))
        case .homePage: HomeView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Listen for the state of authorization and change your `currentPage` based on it: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/start#listen_for_authentication_state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a user is logged in via Firebase Authentication, Auth.auth().currentUser is not nil, you can check for that and show your views accordingly:

```
struct MainView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
                SignView(isLogin: .constant(false))
            } else {
                HomeView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Regarding the currentPage variable, in case you still need it when you use Auth.auth().currentUser, it would be necessary to to save it, for example with `@AppStorage`.